# WordPress jQuery.load() pagination link gives 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to build a jQuery-based next/previous navigation but ran into a roadblock of a weird error. Here's a very much simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
$('.next').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('main').fadeOut();
  $('main').load('/page/2/ main .content', function() {
    $('main').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

The next page link is usually generated dynamically of course.

Clicking on the link gives a 404 error in the Chrome developer tools and the content never loads into the `main` tag. Changing it to a rewrite-less `/?paged=2` also 404's. When inserting a link to a page however (like `/contact/`) works without without a problem. Directly entering the link works as well, so rewriting is working correctly.

This is driving me nuts. Anyone has an idea how to make this work?

Comment: Assuming your js code is present here ABC.com/foo . a) Do you want to load ABC.com/page/2 or ABC.com/foo/page/2? if later try "$('main').load('./page/2/ main .content', function() {" notice the additional dot. b) Prefer using absolute URLs c) Try loading page/2 in browser and check if this page loads correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I still get a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. The page loads correctly when accessed directly, as stated above. Also, what I want to load is `http://domain.com/page/2/`.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I'm stuck with the éxact same problem. I figure it has to do with the fact that I'm buildig the pages with an AJAX call to begin with, but I can't figure out why it won't work. Opening /page/2/ in my browser gives the correct response, but loading it with jQuery gives that exact 404 in the developer window..

Comment: Unfortunately I never found a solution for this. One of many reasons why I since ditched WordPress as a development platform. However, take a look at the recently introduced REST API, it may work more reliable as it was specifically designed for advanced access scenarios like JavaScript frontends.